# Q:How can I get "glossary_id"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I am following the EXACT steps indicated here
  https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/glossary

to create a online glossary.
[description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrfF0.png)

I can get "project-id",but where can I get my "glossary-id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project-id is given, it is the name of your project and you just type to type it the way it is.

The glossary-id, on the contrary, is provided by you, as specified in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#create-glossary)

> where my-project is the project-number-or-id, and my-en-ru-glossary is the glossary-id provided by you.

this means that you are free to set it as you like (and you will have to use it from the time of creation on every time you want to refer to it).

I hope it is clear now!